# Как правильно использовать get_template_part('',''); повторно?

Tags: php, wordpress

Пример вызова get_... на основной странице, никаких лупов.

```
<div class="prices">            
   <?php get_template_part('content','table'); ?>
<div class="row"> ..
```

Вырвал пару кусков с основной страницы, чтоб использовать их на других при помощи `get_template_part('content', 'bla-bla');` на основной странице эти куски отображаются корректно, на следующих эти вставки отображаются полупустыми, например таблица на основной работает отлично, а при повторном использовании, таблица есть, а текста внутри нет. Таблица, как и другие куски заполнены при помощи *Advanced Custom Fields*. Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Разработчики wordpress должны страдать.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, а точнее почти с вероятностю 100%

`<?php get_template_part('content','table'); ?>`

Используется в стандартном loop для WordPress. 
Для указания в чем проблема, Вы хотяби свой кастмный код напишите с скастомного темплейта. 
ACF обычно работает с постом, в таблице пустые значения так як в темплейте например синтаксис написан для работы в лупе, тоесть используються штуки `th_title() th_content()` и т.д. без указания ID поста( например не `the_content($post->ID)` ).